# Problems reading and calculating items in list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to use menus to accepts menu options that append an empty list that acts as a cart. When the list is done with i have the option to add more lists if necessary. In the end im supposed to calculate the total number of carts, total number of items, and the total price. The first issue is the calcuation of carts is wrong as it treats every new entry as list rather than na item, which elads to the item count being wrong as well for each cart. Along with this, i get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" when trying calculating the final price and im just not sure what to do

```
def main():
    #Flag for full checking out or not
    checkout = False
    #Flag to start a new cart or not
    new_cart = True
    #Placeholder list
    cart = []
    #List of items
    book_list = [['My Own Words', 18.00], ['Grant', 24.50], ['The Overstory', 18.95], ['Becoming', 18.99]]
    elec_list = [['HP Laptop', 429.50], ['Eyephone', 790.00], ['Bose Speakers', 220.00]]
    cloth_list = [['T-shirt', 9.50], ['Shoes', 45.00], ['Pants', 24.00], ['Nationals Hat', 32.00]]
    groc_list = [['Coho Salmon', 12.50], ['Spaghetti', 2.75], ['Milk', 3.99], ['Eggs', 1.99], ['Flat Tire Ale', 9.95]]
    while checkout == False or new_cart == True:
        #Main Menu
        if checkout == False:
            #Main Item menu
            print("""
                1 - Books
                2 - Electronics
                3 - Clothes
                4 - Groceries
                c - Continue to checkout
                """)
            choice = input("Select one of the categories or checkout(1-4 or 'c'): ")
            #Variable to return user to past menu
            Return = False 
            if choice == '1':
                while Return == False:
                    #Sub item menu
                    print("""
                            1 - "My Own Words", $18.00
                            2 - "Grant", $24.50
                            3 - "The Overstory", $18.95
                            4 - "Becoming", $18.99
                            x - return to menu
                            """)
                    item = input("Please select from the menu or go back to the categories: ")
                    if item == '1' or item == '2' or item =='3' or item == '4':
                        #Adds item onto the the cart
                        cart.append(book_list[int(item)-1]) 
                    elif item == 'x':
                        #Returns user to main menu
                        Return = True
                    else: print("Invalid input try again")
            elif choice == '2':
                while Return == False:
                    #Sub item menu
                    print("""
                            1 - HP Laptop, $429.50
                            2 - EyePhone 10, $790.00
                            3 - Bose 20 Speakers, $220.00
                            x - return to menu
                            """)
                    item = input("Please select from the menu or go back to the categories: ")
                    if item == '1' or item == '2' or item == '3':
                        #Adds item onto the the cart
                        cart.append(elec_list[int(item)-1])
                    elif item == 'x':
                        Return = True
                    else:
                        print("Invalid input try again")
            elif choice == '3':
                while Return == False:
                    #Sub item menu
                    print("""
                            1 - T-shirt, $9.50
                            2 - Shoes, $45.00
                            3 - Pants, $24.00
                            4 - Nationals Hat, $32.00
                            x - return to menu
                            """)
                    item = input("Please select from the menu or go back to the categories: ")
                    if item == '1' or item == '2' or item == '3':
                        #Adds item onto the the cart
                        cart.append(cloth_list[int(item)-1])
                    elif item == 'x':
                        Return = True
                    else:
                        print("Invalid input try again")
            elif choice == '4':
                while Return == False:
                    #Sub item menu
                    print("""
                        1 – Coho Salmon, $12.50
                        2 − Spaghetti, $2.75
                        3 – Milk, $3.99
                        4 – Eggs, $1.99
                        5 – Flat Tire Ale, $9.95
                        x - return to menu
                        """)
                    item = input("Please select from the menu or go back to the categories: ")
                    if item == '1' or item == '2' or item == '3' or item == '4' or item == '5':
                        #Adds item onto the the cart
                        cart.append(groc_list[int(item)-1])
                    elif item == 'x':
                        Return = True
                    else:
                        print("Invalid input try again")
            elif choice == 'c':
                checkout = True
                print(cart)
            else: print("Invalid input, please try again!")
        else:
            print("Do you want a new cart y/n")
            choice = input()
            if choice == 'y':
                checkout = False
                #Create new cart
                cart.append([])
            elif choice == 'n':
                #Proceed to item summary
                new_cart = False
            else:
                print("Invalid Option, Choose again")
    #Print total number of carts
    print("Total number of carts :",len(cart)) 
    for v in range(len(cart)):
        #Increment for each existing cart
        print("Cart",v+1)
        #Add total number of items within every cart
        print("Total Number of items:",len(cart[v]))
        #Add total price of items within every cart
        print("Total cost of the items: $",sum(cart[v]))
    
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cart contains a list of items which themselves are array:

example, i ran your code and your cart looks like this:

`[['My Own Words', 18.0], ['My Own Words', 18.0], ['My Own Words', 18.0], ['My Own Words', 18.0]]`

you're trying to apply a sum on a position of an array, so for example when you do
`sum(cart[0])` you call sum on `['My Own Words', 18.0]` so your code tries to do:

'My Own Words'+18 which gives a type error.

if all you need is the just the total price you could just append the prices instead of the whole items, or you could simply append the prices to a seperate array and call sum on that

Comment: I understand what you mean. When I see it in the cart list I see what the position the prices are located, however whenever I do sum(cart[0][1]), it still does not go through. can you tell me why that is?

Comment: since the cart contains a list of `[name, price]` you could use `zip(*cart)` which would output two lists: one of names and one of proces. Something like `total = sum(zip(*cart)[1])`

Comment: I tried that however i got the error "TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable" even after trying to make it zip as a list using ```total = sum(list(zip(*cart)[1]))```

Comment: Your [1] is at the wrong position, you want to do sum(list(zip(*cart))[1])

Comment: Even after that I then get the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'